# I try to map values to a column in pandas but i get nan values instead

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my code:

```
mapping = {"ISTJ":1, "ISTP":2, "ISFJ":3, "ISFP":4, "INFP":6, "INTJ":7, "INTP":8, "ESTP":9, "ESTJ":10, "ESFP":11, "ESFJ":12, "ENFP":13, "ENFJ":14, "ENTP":15, "ENTJ":16, "NaN": 17}
q20 = castaway_details["personality_type"]
q20["personality_type"] = q20["personality_type"].map(mapping)
```

the data frame is like this

```
   personality_type  
0   INTP     
1   INFP     
2   INTJ    
3   ISTJ     
4   NAN   
5   ESFP
```

I want the output like this:

```
   personality_type  
0   8     
1   6     
2   7    
3   1     
4   17   
5   11
```

however, what I get from my code is all NANs

Answer (score 2):

Try to [`pandas.Series.str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) before the [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) :

```
q20["personality_type"]= q20["personality_type"].str.strip().map(mapping)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(q20)

   personality_type
0                 8
1                 6
2                 7
3                 1
4                17
5                11
```

Answer (score 1):

The key `NaN` in your mapping dictionary and `NaN` value in your data frame do not match. I have modified the one in your dictionary.

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna('NAN').map(mapping))

   personality_type
0                 8
1                 6
2                 7
3                 1
4                17
5                11
```

Comment: gives me this error ``` 'str' object has no attribute 'fillna' ```

Comment: You may try this `df['personality_type'].astype(str).map(mapping)` as well.

Comment: It works now however the NAN values don't change, they stay NAN, I wonder why.

Comment: I told you the key in your `mapping` is `NAN` and the one in your data set is `NaN`. you need to change the one in the dictionary.